# Using ChronicleMap with generics: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(int,long,long)

Tags: chronicle-map

I have the following class:

```
public class ChronicleMapIndex<K, V> implements Index<K, V> {

    private ChronicleMap<K, V> index;
    private Map<String, String> characteristicsMap;

    public void buildIndex(String name, Map<String, String> characteristicsMap, Path indexPath, Class<?> keyType, Class<?> valueType){
        this.characteristicsMap = characteristicsMap;
        String filename = name + ".bin";
        Path indexFilePath = Paths.get(indexPath + filename);
        try {
            index = (ChronicleMap<K, V>) ChronicleMap
                    .of(keyType, valueType)
                    .name(name)
                    .entries(Long.parseLong(characteristicsMap.get("entries")))
                    .averageValueSize(Double.parseDouble(characteristicsMap.get("averageValueSize")))
                    .averageKeySize(Double.parseDouble(characteristicsMap.get("averageKeySize")))
                    .createOrRecoverPersistedTo(indexFilePath.toFile(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        return index.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        index.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I basically want to store a chronicle maps map in a wrapper function. Here, `K` and `V` are the same as the `keyType` and `valueType` values passed. So I would like the ChronicleMap map to have the same key and value type as `K` and `V`.

However, when I create it, I get the following error:

```
net.openhft.chronicle.hash.ChronicleHashRecoveryFailedException: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(int,long,long)

    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.openWithExistingFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1877)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createWithFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1701)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.recoverPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1655)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createOrRecoverPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1638)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createOrRecoverPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1629)
    at edu.upf.taln.indexer.index.chroniclemap.ChronicleMapIndex.buildIndex(ChronicleMapIndex.java:27)
```

in this line:

```
                .createOrRecoverPersistedTo(indexFilePath.toFile(), true);
```

I was wondering if this error is because I'm doing something wrong with generics.

I am using ChronicleMap 3.19.4 and JNA 5.5.0 in Windows 10.

Here is an individual test you can run easily:

```
    Map<String, String> characteristicsMap = new HashMap<>();
    characteristicsMap.put("entries", Long.toString(123));
    characteristicsMap.put("averageKeySize", Integer.toString(5));
    characteristicsMap.put("averageValueSize", Integer.toString(5));
    String name = "test";
    Path indexPath = Paths.get("D:/trabajo"); // substitute this as needed
    ChronicleMapIndex<String, String> index = new ChronicleMapIndex<>();
    index.buildIndex(name, characteristicsMap, indexPath ,String.class, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generics. You're using Java 12+, and it's not supported. The internal sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl has changed somewhere between version 11 to 14, and is not backwards-compatible.

Our support policy is to only support LTS versions of Java. The highest we support right now is Java 11. Next LTS version (TBC) is 17, and that what we plan to support next.